# Transforming Ansible dictionary list to individual list not showing as expected

Tags: dictionary, ansible

In my code, only the last string list is being displayed in jenkins output. By right all other dictionary value should be listed. Which part am i doing a mistake. Below are the output, sample code. actual output of the transformation and expected output from the dictionary transformation

Sample of value from dictioanary

```
TASK [Task : Task 1 Name ***
skipping: [123.23.22.123] => (item=fileName1.xml) 
skipping: [123.23.22.123] => (item=fileName2.rar) 
ok: [123.23.22.123] => (item=fileName3.png) => {
    "msg": [
        [
            "/home/nityo/host/fileName3.png.25751.2020-08-21@20:50:59~"
        ]
    ]
}
skipping: [123.23.22.123] => (item=fileName4.html) 
ok: [123.23.22.123] => (item=fileName5.war) => {
    "msg": [
        [
            "/home/nityo/host/fileName5.war.backup21092020"
        ]
    ]
}
ok: [123.23.22.123] => (item=fileName6.war) => {
    "msg": [
        [
            "/home/nityo/host/fileName6.war.backup21092020", 
            "/home/nityo/host/fileName6.war.backup19092020"
        ]
    ]
}
```

My ansible task code

```
- name: Transform value
  set_fact:
    dictlist: "{{ item.value[2:] }}"
  with_dict:
    - "{{ configFiles }}"
    - "{{ mavenFiles }}"
    - "{{ content }}"

- name: Task B ***************************************************************
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ dictlist }}"
  when: dictlist is defined
```

Sample output being displayed

```
TASK [Task : Task B ***************************************************************] ***
ok: [123.23.22.123] => (item=/home/nityo/host/fileName6.war.backup21092020) => {
    "msg": "/home/nityo/host/fileName6.war.backup21092020"
}
ok: [123.23.22.123] => (item=/home/nityo/host/fileName6.war.backup19092020) => {
    "msg": "/home/nityo/host/fileName6.war.backup19092020"
}
```

Expected output

```
TASK [Task : Task B ***************************************************************] ***
ok: [123.23.22.123] => (item=/home/nityo/host/fileName3.png.25751.2020-08-21@20:50:59~) => {
    "msg": "/home/nityo/host/fileName3.png.25751.2020-08-21@20:50:59~"
}
ok: [123.23.22.123] => (item=/home/nityo/host/fileName5.war.backup21092020) => {
    "msg": "/home/nityo/host/fileName5.war.backup21092020"
}
ok: [123.23.22.123] => (item=/home/nityo/host/fileName6.war.backup21092020) => {
    "msg": "/home/nityo/host/fileName6.war.backup21092020"
}
ok: [123.23.22.123] => (item=/home/nityo/host/fileName6.war.backup19092020) => {
    "msg": "/home/nityo/host/fileName6.war.backup19092020"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lays here `dictlist: "{{ item.value[2:] }}"`.

This will always overwrite `dictlist` with the last value.
You need check how to append to list or merge lists.

You can elaborate around this `dictlist: "{{ (dictlist | default([])) + item.value }}"`